# How to prevent a search engine from indexing a directory for a particular domain?

Tags: indexing, dns, bots

I have a web hosting package with 2 domains pointing to it. I've noticed on Google that it has indexed the directory of one of the domains for the other domain. Is there a way of preventing this from happening.

Answer (score 4):

You could try with the [Robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) but is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect all pages of one of your domains to the other one. You can do that with .htaccess and modRewrite similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This would perform a 301 redirect (Permanently moved) from example.com to www.example.com.

For SEO purposes you never want to have duplicate content (identical pages on different URLs), there should always be exactly one URL for your content, all other possible URLs should redirect to that one.

Answer (score 2):

Updating your robots.txt will definitely solve the problem in the future, but I think the question you should be asking is, How did Google know those pages were there?

First, you should ensure that a user can't traverse your site's filesystem (if your server is *nix, .htaccess should have something like `Options -Indexes`). And if you had a public link anywhere that joined the two sites on a single domain, that could be how Google found it. If you are careful to keep your site clean and never point to the files in the other docroot, there should be no problem hosting one domain off the subdirectory of another domain.

You can clear Google's index of those pages by using their [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en). In order to identify yourself as the site's owner, you'll need to install a unique file (they create it for you) in the root directory of your various document roots, then you can manually update the parts of your site that they've indexed. This applies *only* to Google.

If you've been indexed by other search engines (and you probably have been if Google indexed you), you should try to figure out how they got there, fix the problem, move the second site to another folder (causing the pages to report `404 Page Not Found` on your main domain) and then get the the search engines to reindex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, then some additions to your .htaccess file would probably work, but the specifics would depend on your site setup.